# wxPython splash screen disappear on click

Tags: wxpython

I am creating app with wxPython. I set s splash screen not to close until i do it myself. But each i click on it, it disappear. Here is my code:

```
splash = wx.adv.SplashScreen(wx.Bitmap('res/splash.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG),
                             wx.adv.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN |
                             wx.adv.SPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT,
                             5000, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                             wx.Point(wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL),
                             wx.DefaultSize,
                             wx.BORDER_SIMPLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
```

I try setting timeout to -1 but nothing:

```
splash = wx.adv.SplashScreen(wx.Bitmap('res/splash.jpg', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_JPEG),
                             wx.adv.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN |
                             wx.adv.SPLASH_NO_TIMEOUT,
                             -1, None, wx.ID_ANY,
                             wx.Point(wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL),
                             wx.DefaultSize,
                             wx.BORDER_SIMPLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
```

Comment: You don't mention your OS or version of wxPython but testing on Linux wxPython 4.2 your code works. Simply omitting the style `wx.adv.SPLASH_TIMEOUT` should be enough.

Comment: I realised that I may have misunderstood your issue. Given that it is a SplashScreen, it is designed to disappear after a given amount of time or when you click on it. Your statement ` But each i click on it, it disappear` could suggest that you want to discard the screen via some other method. If that is the case, simply create your own screen based on a dialog or a panel containing your bitmap and then choose your method of cancelling it.